# Broken webapp: need to disable ipv6 (i.e. use ipv4 only) for a specific host

Tags: windows-10, networking, ipv6

I'm need to use a specific webapp developed by a small company. The webapp uses IP whitelisting. However, there's a problem with that feature: ipv6 is not working. They don't know how to fix it and don't have the resources to work on it now. They advise me to disable ipv6.

So for now, I have disable ipv6 in my home router (like almost everybody, I'm working from home), but that seems a very extreme measure, just for this one broken site.

Instead I would like (using windows 10) to disable ipv6 (use only ipv4) ***ONLY*** for a specific host. Is that possible?
I've searched for this online, but didn't find an answer.

eidt:
I tried to add a windows firewall option (Outbound rule, block connection, protocol type IPv6, specific host Remote address, all other options set to 'any'/all) but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: They could just remove the AAAA record from the webapp's domain?...

Comment: @user1686 if that's something the company has to do: they will not do that for me. I'm not important enough. If that's something I can do at home, please tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost a 3 year old question at this point, but the answer on Windows is to edit the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and add a mapping for the hostname to the IPv4 address.

For example, if you wanted to only access `portal.office.com` via IPv4, you could enter this in your hosts file:

```
13.107.136.8  portal.office.com
```

Then your computer would skip resolving that host via DNS and instead resolve it via the hosts file, and you'd go to it via IPv4.